# Переносится ли запятая причастного оборота при идущем следом приложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Если двумя тире обособляется приложение, а перед ним имеется причастный оборот, относящийся к определяемому слову, запятая ставится перед первым тире - непосредственно после оборота - или она переносится после второго тире?

Например:

> ...известная надежными приводами немецкая компания, сегодня имеющая сборочный цех в России, — «название компании» — предлагает заказчикам интеллектуальные электроприводы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...известная надежными приводами немецкая компания, сегодня имеющая
>   сборочный цех в России, — **«название компании»** — предлагает заказчикам
>   интеллектуальные электроприводы...

Я бы перенёс название компании поближе к определяемому слову -- и не мучился:

*..известная надежными приводами немецкая компания **«название компании»**, сегодня имеющая сборочный цех в России, предлагает заказчикам интеллектуальные электроприводы...*

Answer (score 0):

Здесь, как я понимаю, зависит от того, к чему относится приложение. Если (гипотетически) это приложение к слову, включенному в состав причастного оборота, то пред приложением остается только одно тире, а после - одна запятая. Но это не наш случай.

Если же, как у нас, приложение относится к определяемому причастным оборотом слову, то причин переносить запятую в конец всей конструкции просто нет, подобная рекомендация относится к другим случаям. Ну а в остальном slava1947 прав.